# Keep completeness of record when subsetting time series datasets in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, subset

I'll explain the problem better. I have downloaded from a databasee some 300,000 observations for a time span of 16 years. 
I want to subset the database by taking in account completeness.

- I want to keep only the observations that are complete in terms of year.

Example: assuming 3 different items (A,B and C) and a time frame of 5 years.

For item A I have observation from years 1 to 5; for item B I have observations from years 1,2,4,5; from item C I have only year 3.

I want to subset the dataset so that the new dataset will only contain item A.

How can I translate this in to code?

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, having not seen the data,

```
name <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c')
year <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
data <- data.frame(name, year)

tmp <- aggregate(year ~ name, data, length)
tmp1 <- subset(tmp, year >=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## A solution using data.table

```
require(data.table)

name <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c')
year <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
data <- data.table(name, year)

name.count <- data[, .N, by = name]
name.keep <- name.count[N >= 5, name]
data.subset <- data[name %chin% name.keep]
```

You could use `data <- data[complete.cases(data)]` before the subsetting step, to remove rows containing NAs.